# How do i create different Jquery function for each buttons?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form which have five buttons and several checkboxes holding different values.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="create-user">
    <button type="button" name="new-user">New</button>
    <button type="button" name="activate-user">Activate</button>
    <button type="button" name="block-user">Block</button>
    <button type="button" name="unblock-user">Unblock</button>
    <button type="button" name="delete-user">Delete</button>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1>" name="userId[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="2>" name="userId[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="3>" name="userId[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="4>" name="userId[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="5>" name="userId[]" />
</form>
```

now based on JavaScript event like onclick, i would like to perform different action for different buttons, for example.

a) `<button type="button" name="new-user">New</button>`

> When User click this button it should redirect to following url.`'index.php?users&option=create'`.

b) `<button type="button" name="activate-user">Activate</button>`

> this button is used for Ajax, it should fetch the selected checkbox value in an array i.e `userId[]`, and send the data to `manage-users.php` and update form after receiving the response. and the rest three buttons Block, Unblock and Delete follows the same procedure as this.

And all this should be done using JQuery, as i am still a novice in JS/JQuery, i would appreicate if someone could guide me with creating JQuery function.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to add an `id` attribute to your buttons so you can easily target them with jQuery.

For example:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="create-user">
    <button type="button" name="new-user" id="new-user">New</button>
    <button type="button" name="activate-user" id="activate-user">Activate</button>
    <button type="button" name="block-user" id="block-user">Block</button>
    <button type="button" name="unblock-user" id="unblock-user">Unblock</button>
    <button type="button" name="delete-user" id="delete-user">Delete</button>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1>" name="userId[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="2>" name="userId[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="3>" name="userId[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="4>" name="userId[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="5>" name="userId[]" />
</form>
```

Then use jQuery to attach handlers for the click event on the buttons like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function(){
        $('#new-user').click(function() {
            // do your code here
        });
        $('#activate-user').click(function() {
            // do your code here
        });
        $('#block-user').click(function() {
            // do your code here
        });
        $('#unblock-user').click(function() {
            // do your code here
        });
        $('#delete-user').click(function() {
            // do your code here
        });
    });
</script>
```

That is not to say that you have to use `id`s to target the buttons you could use something like the following with your current HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function(){
        $('button[name="new-user"]').click(function() {
            // do your code here
        });
        $('button[name="activate-user"]').click(function() {
            // do your code here
        });
        $('button[name="block-user"]').click(function() {
            // do your code here
        });
        $('button[name="unblock-user"]').click(function() {
            // do your code here
        });
        $('button[name="delete-user"]').click(function() {
            // do your code here
        });
    });
</script>
```

`id`s are considered better practice though and are faster for the browser to locate in the DOM than search by attribute like in my last example.

Comment: this looks so nice, however can't is use  `$("button[name='new-user']").click(function()` instead of the id attribute?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar yes you can, but as I mentioned in my answer above `id`s are considered better practice though and are faster for the browser to locate in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to create a selector for each button and attaching an event handler for each matched element. Example

```
$("button[name='new-user']").click(function() {
   window.location = "index.php?users&option=create";
});
```

What happens here is that

1. `$("button[name='new-user']")` finds each button element with the name *new-user*
2. `.click(param)` attaches an event handler to each element found in step one. The event handler is called when an `onclick` event is fired
3. As the param for `click` we create new function that is executed as the event handler
4. `window.location` instructs the browser to change the current URL.

It is probably faster to execute if you use an id attribute to identify each button. Then the jQuery selector `$("#new-button")` would be able to use `document.getElementById` to find the button in question.

I suggest you dive into the jQuery documentation as it is exceptionally good and provides code examples on all functions. After you have tried to do something it's time to ask what you have done wrong here.

Also, depending on your target audience, it is usually a good idea to provide graceful degradation in case javascript is not supported (screen readers, mobile devices, etc). If the navigation is entirely done using javascript there's a certain set of users that cannot use the service at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) and respond accordingly to the button clicked:

```
$('button').click(function(event){
   var name= event.target.name;
   if (name == 'delete-user'){
     //delete the user
   }else if (name == 'new-user'){
     // and so on

});
```

Comment: I don't like this approach. What if there are buttons on the screen that are not be handled by this function (it gets triggered for every button regardless)? Even if it doesn't do anything your still stealing the users processor cycles.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to put an attribute (like id) on each button and then read that id  $(this).attr("id") to figure out which button was pushed during the event callback: